# CSS li background issue

Tags: css

I have a horizontal nav and I'm trying to use images for the li classes however, when I try `.nav li .home{background:img url;}` the image doesnt show, how can I fix this?

CSS

```
.nav {
    position: absolute;
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(images/nav.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
}
.nav li {
    padding-left: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
}
.nav li a {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.nav li.home {
    background: url(images/home.png);
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li>
<a herf="#" class="home">home</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

> I'm trying to use images for the li classes

`.nav li .home` does not target the li. It will target elements with class name of "home" within the li. Without HTML source code, I cannot give a definite solution. But if I were to guess, your HTML is like this:

```
<ul>
 <li class="home">
  <a href="index.html">home</a>
 </li>
 <li class="about">
  <a href="about.html">about</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

In this case, you would change your CSS to:

```
.nav li.home
```

By removing the space, the li is targeted.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the op with html source code.  I tried your suggestion but I am still unable to get images/home.png to show.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<li>` has to have a value - otherwise it won't appear. You can use `&nbsp;` or real text like "home" and set text-indent: -999; to move it offscreen.

Comment: Really confused now.  This makes perfect sense however I still can't seem to get the background image to show.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Your selector
`.nav li.home` 
Will select list items with the class 'home'
In your case, the list items do not have a class .home, it's the links inside the list item that has the class. `li.home` would have worked on the following lines of html:

```
<ul class="nav">
<li class='home'>
<a herf="#"></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

but when you edit this line  to `.nav li .home` with a whitespace between the li and the .home, it will select the elements with class home "inside" the list item. In that case, the background will be added to the `<a herf="#" class="home"></a>` , so the image will be a link. It's both possible.

You also have to give the element with the background a width and a height to fit the background image. if the element is 0x0, you can't see the background.

Did you also check the url? if you go to the path of the image directly in your browser, does it give you a 404 error?